# How does Zoro speak with a sword in his mouth?

Tags: one-piece

When using Santoryu (Three Swords style), Zoro holds a sword in his mouth. How is he able to speak normally, without the sword falling?
[image: Zoro speaking with a sword in mouth]

Comment: anything can be achieved through practise :P

Comment: Have you never see a ventriloquist? It's not the official answer but it is totally consistant.

Answer (score 15):

The official explanation given by the author, Oda Eiichiro, in his SBS<sup>1</sup> column, is that it is Zoro's *heart* speaking. This may not sound any more convincing than [Artistic License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license), but One Piece regularly relies on such unusual logic, so it is not entirely out of place.

---

<sup>1</sup> SBS (Shitsumon wo Boshū Suru, roughly meaning "I'm Taking Questions") is a Q&A column in which Eiichiro Oda answers questions sent in by his fans.

Answer (score 0):

I hate how people always ask this question...
Okay, put a pen in your mouth, try speaking
You will be able to speak, despite the pen being in your mouth. Sure, your voice sounds muffled, but Zoro's voice is also muffled when he speaks with a sword in his mouth
You don't need to move your teeth in order to talk, just your tongue, which I'm pretty sure isn't wrapped around Zoro's sword.
I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

You know those techinique things? Zoro's "three sword style" technique require him to have a third sword, enableing him to perform that technique

Comment: The question is how can he speak with a sword in his mouth. Your answer does not seem to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess yes, it can be done. You know the words won't behaving so much clarity but yes, if you hold the sword hilt with your teeth, you are able to speak out.