# What happens to Zoro's scabbards when he's in a fight?

Tags: one-piece

Various times, when Zoro is fighting, his scabbards just disappear mid fight. Especially when it is convenient, because he is doing motions that require a lot of flexibility and what not. So, I imagine it is just easier to help with the battle to act like his scabbards do not exist but is there a good reason for this that I am missing?

I have been surprised by the answers to weird questions I have had about anime on the internet so I want to see if someone can give me a rational explanation for this. Thanks!

Comment: This is just oppinion based but I think Zoro scabbards are one of many Oda's jokes. Zoro keep's commenting on Luffy throwing his own scabbard during the Wano arc so...

Comment: Recently this has not been happening to my knowledge so idk.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a "mistake" or something similar, but I don't think that would do it justice. Not to take away from the time, effort, and skill of One Piece's artists or Oda-sensei himself, but you'll find in many of Oda's SBS columns (a section of the manga in which Oda, OP's creator, answers questions from his fans), that these kinds of questions are typically answered in a somewhat silly way. Although there's a clear effort to minimize such "mistakes," their importance is obviously not the most important thing to Oda. You'll find a favorite example of such an answer on the top answer of [this thread](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/how-does-zoro-speak-with-a-sword-in-his-mouth). Not so satisfying for everyone, but if you'll excuse the speculation, I'd imagine Oda would give you an answer with the spirit of "Sometimes he doesn't like to wear them. He'll pick them up later."